# navigator.getUserMedia not working on Android / Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, media

do you have any idea of why the following code doesn't work on `Android/Chrome`?

It works well on `Desktop/Chrome`.

```js
function console_log(data) {
 console.log(data)
 var data_str = String(data);
 var $div = $('<div></div>');
 $div.append(data_str);
 $('.console').append($div);
}
$(function(){
 var constraints = { audio: true, video:false }
 //---
 console_log('navigator.mediaDevices...');
 console_log(navigator.mediaDevices);
 //---
 // # TEST 01 #
 var userMedia = navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, function(){
  console_log('---');
  console_log('# TEST 01 # Inside Success Callback');
 }, function(err){
  console_log('---');
  console_log('# TEST 01 # Inside Error Callback');
  console_log(err);
 });
 //---
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
  console_log('---');
  console_log('# TEST 02 # Inside Success Callback');
 }).catch(function(err) {
  console_log('---');
  console_log('# TEST 02 # Inside Error Callback');
  console_log(err);
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.console {
 font-family: monospace;
 white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="console"></div>
```

Just in case, here you have the JSFiddle links:

https://jsfiddle.net/2yum1a0w

For success, open with `Desktop/Chrome` and go to section: `Result`...

https://jsfiddle.net/2yum1a0w/embedded

On `Desktop/Chrome` I get:

```
navigator.mediaDevices...
[object MediaDevices]
---
# TEST 01 # Inside Success Callback
---
# TEST 02 # Inside Success Callback
```

On `Android/Chrome` I get:

```
navigator.mediaDevices...
[object MediaDevices]
---
# TEST 01 # Inside Error Callback
NotAllowedError: Permission denied
---
# TEST 02 # Inside Error Callback
NotAllowedError: Permission denied
```

And by the way, on `Desktop/Firefox` I get:

```
navigator.mediaDevices...
[object MediaDevices]
```

along with the following console error:

```
TypeError: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function
```

Do you have any idea on how to make this work on `Android/Chrome`?

**EDIT 1**

Based on the answer from `Joseph Gordy` below, I tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/wrmvn8k4/

https://jsfiddle.net/wrmvn8k4/embedded

which now works properly on `Desktop/Firefox` getting:

```
navigator.mediaDevices...
[object MediaDevices]
---
# TEST # Inside Success Callback
```

but on `Android/Chrome` I get:

```
navigator.mediaDevices...
[object MediaDevices]
---
# TEST # Inside Error Callback
NotAllowedError: Permission denied
```

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem. `Permission denied` w/out asking..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Mobile browser even haven't asked about permissions. 
And the reason was SSL! You have to use secure connection

Check "Secure context required" section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I have this problem with a fully secure https connection.

Comment: If it's a problem with SSL, then how did you solve it?

Comment: Have you guys found any solution for this problem ? @AhmedGhrib

Comment: it is any solution to this problem? im stuck in a same escenario.  does anyone resolve it?... how?

Comment: Install an SSL certificate to fix. Lookup a free certificate from Certbot.

Answer (score 3):

According to MDN, `navigator.getUserMedia()` is deprecated and isn't supported on Android/Chrome and some newer browser versions. Use [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) instead. You can check browser compatibility below.

[MDN Navigator.getUserMedia browser check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility)

Here's a partial example I've used to access the camera for video streaming in a past project. The browser should ask the user for access on the device.

```
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video:  cameraOrientation })
    .then(function(stream) {
      if ("srcObject" in video) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
        } else {
          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          video.play();
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: now it works on `Desktop/Firefox` but still not working on `Android/Chrome`, please, check my `EDIT 1` on my original post for more details. Thanks!

Comment: On android, Chrome should show a notification asking for permission from the user to be able to access that media (In your case it looks like the microphone). Google doesn't want a site or app to access the camera or microphone without the users permission. The `Permission denied` makes me think the notification was blocked or did not show.

Comment: Just tested the `https://jsfiddle.net/wrmvn8k4/embedded` on my Android device. I received the notification and after giving the site permission, it successfully accessed my microphone. It also gave me this on the screen: `navigator.mediaDevices...
[object MediaDevices]
---
# TEST # Inside Success Callback`

Comment: did you try `Android/Chrome` or `Android/Native browser`?. It works for me on the second case.

Comment: I have faced the same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59579227/how-to-stream-webcam-into-mobile-browser-by-using-reactjs . But, I did not find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
I was also having the same problem,
But I solved it,
My camera was blocked, U might have blocked it too,
Go to settings and check the site settings,

I hope it helps U