# How to stream webcam into mobile browser by using ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I have created a simple react app that streams the webcam video stream on the browser. Here's the link to the github project :  [Basic WebCam Streamer](https://github.com/AGSTRANGER/Basic-WebCam-Streamer)
The code is pretty simple and straightforward :

```
class AppStreamCam extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.streamCamVideo= this.streamCamVideo.bind(this)
  }
  streamCamVideo() {
    var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } };
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function(mediaStream) {
        var video = document.querySelector("video");

        video.srcObject = mediaStream;
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          video.play();
        };
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
      }); // always check for errors at the end.
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="container">
          <video autoPlay={true} id="videoElement" controls></video>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.streamCamVideo}>Start streaming</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the result :
[image]

Once, I click on the button, the webcam turns on and starts streaming into the browser.
Here's my ***problem***:
When I open chrome on my phone and enter the localServer address, and click on the button, the app crashes since ***obviously*** the app code is meant to be run from the pc browser so that it may turn the pc webcam.

So when I click on the button from my phone, I ***understandably*** get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined

My ***goal*** is to click on the button from my mobile browser and start streaming the pc webcam on my mobile browser just like on the pc.

However, I do not know from where to start exactly. Any help?

Comment: I have noticed that someone else has faced a somewhat similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862313/navigator-getusermedia-not-working-on-android-chrome . However, it hasn't been answered yet ... Apparently, the connexion needs to be done with SSL from the mobile browser

Comment: After doing some consoleLogging, I found-out that the navigator object isn't accessible in the mobile chrome? Why is this the case?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

`"getUserMedia() is a powerful feature which can only be used in secure contexts; in insecure contexts, navigator.mediaDevices is undefined, preventing access to getUserMedia(). A secure context is, in short, a page loaded using HTTPS or the file:/// URL scheme, or a page loaded from localhost."`

Comment: @pmiranda thanks for this explanation, I'm triying to work with mi mobile in my localhost and never open the camera, and that's the reason

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.
1. Open *package.json* and paste this inside *scripts*:

> "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"

This should serve the app over https
2. If this gives you this error:

> React app error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure
>   WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over
>   HTTPS

Open

> node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js

And paste this code inside the definition of the *connection*:

```
protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',
```

This is apparently a bug in *react-sripts* that hasn't been solved yet. If https protocol is being used we should use WebSockets over SSL/TLS (WSS) protocol instead of WebSockets (WS). You can learn more about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8079#issuecomment-562373869):

**NOTE:** This will not stream your pc webcam into your phone but rather the phone's camera.